# How to thresholding image by ourselves without using fucntion in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, assertion, threshold

I'm new in OpenCV, and I want to thresholding the image by myself without using Threshold function in opencv, because the time spend on function threshold is to high for me.

Here is my code:

```
Mat src = imread("D:\\DataBox\\7.jpg", 0);
for (int i = 0; i < src.cols; i++) {
    cout << i << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < src.rows; j++) {
        if (src.at<uchar>(i, j) > 70) {
            src.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
            cout << j << endl;
        }
        else
            src.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
    }
}
```

but it still says:

> "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file C:\Program Files\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 894"

I can print j from 0~719(since the size of the image is 720*960), but as long as the parameter i want to become 2 from 1, the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up `rows` and `cols`:

Try this:

```
Mat src = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++) 
{
    //cout << i << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++) 
    {
        if (src.at<uchar>(i, j) > 70) {
            src.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
            //cout << j << endl;
        }
        else
            src.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
    }
}
```

This is, however very unlikely to perform better than OpenCV implementation. You can gain a little speed working on raw pointers, with a little trick to work on continuous data when possible:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat src = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\nice.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    int rows = src.rows;
    int cols = src.cols;
    if (src.isContinuous())
    {
        cols = rows * cols;
        rows = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        uchar* pdata = src.ptr<uchar>(i);
        int base = i*cols;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (pdata[base + j] > 70)
            {
                pdata[base + j] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pdata[base + j] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Actually, on my PC my version is a little bit faster than OpenCV one:

```
Time @HenryChen (ms):   2.83266
Time @Miki (ms):        1.09597
Time @OpenCV (ms):      2.10727
```

You can test on your PC with the following code, since time depends on many factor, e.g. optimizations enabled in OpenCV:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat1b src(720,960);
    randu(src, 0, 256);

    Mat1b src1 = src.clone();
    Mat1b src2 = src.clone();
    Mat1b src3 = src.clone();

    double tic1 = double(getTickCount());

    // Method @HenryChen (corrected)
    for (int i = 0; i < src1.rows; i++)
    {
        //cout << i << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < src1.cols; j++)
        {
            if (src1.at<uchar>(i, j) > 70) {
                src1.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
                //cout << j << endl;
            }
            else
                src1.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
        }
    }

    double toc1 = (double(getTickCount()) - tic1) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Time @HenryChen (ms): \t" << toc1 << endl;

    //-------------------------------------

    double tic2 = double(getTickCount());

    // Method @Miki
    int rows = src2.rows;
    int cols = src2.cols;
    if (src2.isContinuous())
    {
        cols = rows * cols;
        rows = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        uchar* pdata = src2.ptr<uchar>(0);
        int base = i*cols;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            pdata[base + j] = (pdata[base + j] > 70) ? uchar(0) : uchar(255);
        }
    }

    double toc2 = (double(getTickCount()) - tic2) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Time @Miki (ms): \t" << toc2 << endl;

    //-------------------------------------

    double tic3 = double(getTickCount());

    // Method @OpenCV
    threshold(src3, src3, 70, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    double toc3 = (double(getTickCount()) - tic3) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Time @OpenCV (ms): \t" << toc3 << endl;


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you solve my problem, indeed is the mis-order of row and column.

Comment: The function of threshold runs 0.436mn, my for loop runs 42ms, and your method is about 1ms. I'm searching for less time consume below 0.436ms

Comment: What's your image size?

Comment: Actually in my test my pointer version is faster than `cv::threshold`. Did you run it in release mode?

Comment: The size is 720*960.  Im sorry, what is "marking as the answer then"??

Comment: What you just did ;D.

Comment: I just posted my benchmark. Please have a look, and remember to run in release mode!

Comment: Thanks a lot Miki ! I'm appreciate for your patient ! But I'm wondering why there are different result between our computers? Is it because the CPU?

Comment: Probably. Also it depends on the optimizations enabled on OpenCV (cuda, ipp, sse, ...) and probably also the kind of images, which might affect branch prediction in the loop

Comment: I see. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry to bothor you again, I don't quiet understand how your "row pointer" works, can you simply explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `test.at<uchar>(cv::Point(i, j))` instead. I always get lost when accessing cv::Mat directly - cv::Point clears it up a little bit.

Anyway, I agree with Miki - it is very unlikely to create a function that performs better that a library one.